# Compiling Codeigniter's User Guide

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm pulling latest Codeigniter from

> https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter

However, when I check this user-guide page

> https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/tree/develop/user_guide_src

It is not something that I can view. It should have been HTML. It needs to be compiled I think.
I don't want to use

> http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/

this guide because it is not as updated as this one. 
There have been a lot of enhancements after 2.1.0 stable released. 
How to compile this?
Actually it is written on the Codeigniter page. But I have never forked CI. How can I do it?

> So where's the HTML?
>
> Obviously, the HTML documentation is what we care most about, as it is
>   the primary documentation that our users encounter. Since revisions to
>   the built files are not of value, they are not under source control.
>   This also allows you to regenerate as necessary if you want to
>   "preview" your work. Generating the HTML is very simple. From the root
>   directory of your user guide repo fork issue the command you used at
>   the end of the installation instructions:
>
> make html You will see it do a whiz-bang compilation, at which point
>   the fully rendered user guide and images will be in build/html/. After
>   the HTML has been built, each successive build will only rebuild files
>   that have changed, saving considerable time. If for any reason you
>   want to "reset" your build files, simply delete the build folder's
>   contents and rebuild.

I found how I can do it. However, my host "Hostgator" doesn't not allow me to install sphinx. I think it will be better to ask an Unix user to compile it for me .

Answer (score 1):

read the documentation...

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/user_guide_src/README.rst

download the guide to your local machine and compile it yourself.

Comment: The problem is I'm using windows. I checked there are solutions for windows too. But you have to install a lot of services to windows. I think somebody should compile it for me.